# Play socket-streamed h.264 movie on iOS using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I’m working on a small iPhone app which is streaming movie content over a network connection using regular sockets. The video is in `H.264` format. I’m however having difficulties with playing/decoding the data. I’ve been considering using `FFMPEG`, but the license makes it unsuitable for the project. I’ve been looking into Apple’s `AVFoundation` framework (`AVPlayer` in particular), which seems to be able to handle h264 content, however I’m only able to find methods to initiate the movie using an url – not by proving a memory buffer streamed from the network.

I’ve been doing some tests to make this happen anyway, using the following approaches:

1. Play the movie using a regular `AVPlayer`. Every time data is received on the network, it’s written to a file using fopen with append-mode. The `AVPlayer`’s asset is then reloaded/recreated with  the updated data. There seems to be two issues with this approach: firstly, the screen goes black for a short moment while the first asset is unloaded and the new loaded. Secondly, I do not know exactly where the playing stopped, so I’m unsure how I would find out the right place to start playing the new asset from.
2. The second approach is to write the data to the file as in the first approach, but with the difference that the data is loaded into a second asset. A `AVQueuedPlayer` is then used where the second asset is inserted/queued in the player and then called when the buffering has been done. The first asset can then be unloaded without a black screen. However, using this approach it’s even more troublesome (than the first approach) to find out where to start playing the new asset.

Has anyone done something like this and made it work? Is there a proper way of doing this using `AVFoundation`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I, too, am trying to play a h264 file (.264 file extension) containing a single frame and trying to decode it.  AVAssetReader doesn't accept this file format and the only plan I have is to create a mp4 file per frame (this sounds crazy).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the source has to push the video rather than having the app pull it? HLS usually works the other way round. If your source machine can run OSX, there are Apple tools to do the segmenting for you from a UDP rtsp input stream.  If not, you could possibly fake out the AVPlayer into thinking it's dealing with normal HLS by running a proxy on the phone- chunk your file as it arrives, and write some code to generate an appropriate fake .m3u8 playlist to represent the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The official method to do this is the HTTP Live Streaming format which supports multiple quality levels (among other things) and automatically switches between them (eg: if the user moves from WiFi to cellular).

You can find the docs here: [Apple Http Streaming Docs](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/)

Comment: Is there any way to stream web socket data to play video with AVPlayer.