# Method to consume web socket video stream with AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, websocket, video-streaming, avfoundation

I have a resource sending a video stream via websockets (I don't have control over the transimission method).  I am able to read from the socket using [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) without any problems, but `AVPlayer` and its ilk need an `NSURL`, not a stream of `NSData` bytes.

Here are a couple of solutions that I have tried:

1. **Custom `NSURLProtocol` to route the bytes from the socket to a `NSURLProtocolClient`.**  It turns out, though, that `AVPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayerViewController` do not use `NSURLConnection`.
2. **[This similarly worded question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804694/play-socket-streamed-h-264-movie-on-ios-using-avfoundation) tried writing the bytes to disk and appending them** with poor results.
3. **Use [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) to proxy the stream.** The APIs here (unless I'm missing something) aren't conducive to writing an arbitrary amount of data to a response.

**How can I trick AVPlayer into playing my video stream?**

Comment: You'll need to either write the (presumably) H.264/AAC data to an MP4 file, or use an HTTP server and serve an HLS stream for AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer to play back.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). This allows you to initialize an `AVAsset` with a custom URL like `myapp://path/that/means/something/to/myapp` and if you have set `[[AVAsset resourceLoader] setDelegate:myObj queue:myQueue]` then the media playback pipeline will ask you for some data and it merely requires you to respond with some NSData - see [AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest respondWithData:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest/respondWithData:).